# Square symmetric matrix and its determinant to prove positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-semidefinite

I'm studying a strange example; the goal is to find the $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the real symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite.

**First method**
To do so, is it correct to impose the determinant is non negative?

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c \\
c & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
0 \leq det(A) = 1 - c^2 \quad \rightarrow \quad -1 \leq c \leq 1
$$

**Second method** If I apply the principal minors criterion, I should consider the two minors of $A$ and if they are non negative, the matrix is positive semidefinite.

There are two principal minors $det(1)= 1 > 0$ (deleting second row and column) and $det(1)= 1 > 0$ (deleting first row and column). So in this case $A$ is positive semidefinite (actually is positive definite) for all $c$.

The two methods give different results.

Comment: The $2\times 2$ matrices $[\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\\b & c\end{smallmatrix}]$ has **3** principal minors: $a, c$ and $ac-b^2$.

Comment: Hello @achillehui but $ac-b^2$ is not a principal minor; to find a principal minor you should delete a row and a column with the same index.

Comment: To apply principal minor criterion to a $n \times n$ matrix, you need to check all principal minor (obtained by deleting $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ rows/columns).

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi That is not true

Comment: Hi @BenGrossmann thank you for the comment. Could you suggest me any link or book where to find theory and or examples about that?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) on Sylvester's criterion. If you prefer a textbook reference, see Carl D. Meyer, Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra. See section 7.6 Positive Definite Matrices, page 566.